# $.getJSON saying property is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using this code to communicate with the API. I'm trying to just output the URL

```
$.getJSON("TilesHandlers/GetLastAccessedCourses.ashx?history=yes", function (data) {

        $.each(data.last_courses.Items, function (key, val) {
             console.log(val.url);

        });

    });
```

When I enter the code in chrome, I get the number 18 and then undefined in the response.

This is the json output:

```
{
    "last_courses": {
        "Tile_title": "",
        "Items": {
            "Type": "Course",
            "IsOnline": "True",
            "CourseID": "55b40830-1c34-43ca-ba9d-342a69ba0a79",
            "Title": "Course C1",
            "Code": "c1",
            "Description": "description",
            "ProgramID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "CourseProgram": "Provide-commerce",
            "DateEnrolled": "07/08/2014",
            "CourseStartDate": "07/08/2014",
            "LastModule": "",
            "LastModuleName": "",
            "LastDateAttempted": "",
            "AllowModal": "",
            "StatusDetail": "overdue",
            "url": "launchEnterClassrooom('55b40830-1c34-43ca-ba9d-342a69ba0a79', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '', '1', '600', '800', '', 'Course C1')",
            "Status": "Active",
            "PercentCompleted": "0"
        },
        "New": "0",
        "Started": "0",
        "Completed": "0",
        "Overdue": "1",
        "Due": "0",
        "Expired": "0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like you are trying to fetch the url, just do console.log(data.last_courses.Items.url)

your code is throwing error for items is an objct and not an array

Answer (score 0):

`Items` is an `object` not an `array`.

You do not need to iterate on it.

so you can directly fetch the url property value.

yo  have to do :

```
console.log(data.last_courses.Items.url)
```

### DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/npv34udg/

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined